# Additional logging for django.contrib.auth

Tags: python, django, session, authentication

I want to log when session hash verification fails. The logging code should be inserted inside this [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py#L183](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L183) if block.

I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to implement this. Currently it looks like I will need to override the whole `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`.

Do you have any tips for me?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you copy [get_user](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L159) function and put the logger like you want to:

```
from django.contrib.auth import *    

def your_get_user(request):
    """
    Returns the user model instance associated with the given request session.
    If no user is retrieved an instance of `AnonymousUser` is returned.
    """
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AnonymousUser
    user = None
    try:
        user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
        backend_path = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        if backend_path in settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS:
            backend = load_backend(backend_path)
            user = backend.get_user(user_id)
            # Verify the session
            if ('django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'
                    in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and hasattr(user, 'get_session_auth_hash')):
                session_hash = request.session.get(HASH_SESSION_KEY)
                session_hash_verified = session_hash and constant_time_compare(
                    session_hash,
                    user.get_session_auth_hash()
                )
                if not session_hash_verified:
                    log = logging.getLogger("YourLog")
                    log.debug(session_hash)
                    request.session.flush()
                    user = None

    return user or AnonymousUser()
```

And use this like you want to in your code